# Why gulp-livereload crashes with Error: listen EADDRINUSE?

Tags: gulp, gulp-livereload

I use [`gulp-livereload`](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload) in my [`gulpfile.js`](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer/blob/master/gulpfile.js).

It works fine for CSS files, but crashes for HTML files.

For example, everytime I save `index.html`, gulp crashes with the error below.

Why is this happening?

<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer)</kbd>

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/Users/mishamoroshko/github-explorer/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:556:24)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/mishamoroshko/github-explorer/gulpfile.js:64:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/mishamoroshko/github-explorer/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/mishamoroshko/github-explorer/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/mishamoroshko/github-explorer/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at /Users/mishamoroshko/github-explorer/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:279:18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you're loading `connect-livereload`, you can simply use the gulp plugin. Your error may be a conflict with the two, since they use the same ports.

So change your *Gulpfile* to :

```
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('watch', function() {

  livereload.listen();

  gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['jshint']).on('change', livereload.changed);
  gulp.watch(paths.styles, ['less']).on('change', livereload.changed);
  gulp.watch(paths.views).on('change', livereload.changed);

});

gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/app.less')
    .pipe(less({
      paths: []
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

And remove all the `connect-livereload` parts.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I updated [the repo](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer) with your suggestion. The problem now is that it reloads the `*.less` file (rather than *.css) which is not very helpful. Also, when I modify a `*.js` file (e.g. `home-controller.js`) it says `home-controller.js was reloaded` but doesn't refresh the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Hum for the first problem, you may want to pipe the livereload after the `less` conversion is finished, so at the end of your `less` task. Can you please try this with the `jshint`task too ? Update my answer for an example

Comment: Tried that, but now it's the same problem as with JS files. It says "app.css was reloaded", but doesn't refresh the browser. I also tried to pipe livereload in the jshint task, but no luck, browser is not refreshed (also there is a side effect of reloading ALL the scripts rather than just the one I modified). Again, I updated the repo.

Comment: I created a new, more focused, question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26062244/247243
as the original problem of this question is resolved! Thanks, and if you can help with this other question, that would be great!

Comment: Yep good idea, since this error is now gone, will continue on your problem anyway

Comment: Appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 6):

The port you are using to serve the files already has something listening on that port.